Error while configuring hyperledger explorer using fabric-ca
Explorer logs:
Error instantiating FabricCAServices  Error: Calling enroll endpoint failed, CONNECTION Timeout
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/opt/explorer/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClient.js:315:13)
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:481:8)
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)

Fabric CA logs:
2024/05/13 10:32:49 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org'

This is the configuration of the .json config for explorer
"certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca_org": {
            "url": "https://ca_org:12054",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org.example.com/ca/ca.org.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "caName": "ca-org"
        }
    }

ca configuration is same as below:
services:
  ca_org:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.5.9
    labels:
      service: hyperledger-fabric
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=12054      
    ports:
      - "12054:12054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ../fabric-ca/org:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_org

common name settings in .yaml:
csr:
cn: ca.org.example.com
   hosts:
     - localhost
     - org.example.com

how can i solve this issue? let me know...

is the host (in the cert in use) for Common Name (CN) / Subject Alternative Name (SAN) set to the ip-address/dns name you're using? or is it ca-org

added the configuration of my ca. Also I have two other org configured the same way and explorer isn't showing any error for them. for this specific org which i have added later it throws an error.
